# Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory] is not instantiable

Tags: lumen

I am trying to return a response like this:

```
return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA']);
```

however, I got error:

```
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory] is not instantiable.
```

Any idea?

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/lumen",
  "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel",
    "lumen"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "generationtux/jwt-artisan": "^0.1.7",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.0",
    "neomerx/cors-illuminate": "^1.1",
    "fenos/notifynder": "3.1.*",
    "franzose/closure-table": "^4.1",
    "mlntn/lumen-artisan-serve": "~1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "league/flysystem": " ~1.0",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "GuzzleHttp\\": "/vendor/guzzlehttp/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "database/"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
      "tests/",
      "database/"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json`?

Comment: Kindly see the composer.json added to the question above

Comment: as a test, if you remove `bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel`, do you still get the error?

Answer (score 13):

I still get the error in 2020. Here's an updated version of the solution by @sunben:

In **bootstrap/app.php**, uncomment the following line

`$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);`

Then in **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**, update register method to add:

```php
$this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class, function() {
    return new \Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

call

`use Tests\TestCase;`

instead of

`use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

your function depends on another function, So you should extend like **feature** test and not **unit** tests.

Answer (score 4):

Might be late but found the solution.

In **bootstrap/app.php**, uncomment the following line

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

Then in **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**, update register method to add:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory', function ($app) {
        return new \Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory(
            $app['Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory'],
            $app['Illuminate\Routing\Redirector']
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `response` helper may be used to conveniently generate other types of response instances. When the `response` helper is called without arguments, an implementation of the Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory class is returned.

`use Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory;`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this
`public function register() { $this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class, function() { return new \Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory(); }); $this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator::class, function ($app) { return new \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator($app); }); }`

Answer (score 0):

Those who are still getting routing related error, just put the following line in your `composer.json` file and run the command `composer update`

```
"illuminate/routing": "^5.6"

composer update
```

and boom here we go, wish all things are working great now

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48678862/9751944

@sunben's answer worked for me but I added the following inside the register method

```
$this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollectionInterface::class, function ($app) { return new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection; });
```